# How does signed floating point adder implement?

Tags: computer-architecture, arithmetic, floating-point

The following picture is a block diagram of an arithmetic unit dedicated to IEEE 754 floating-point addition from [Computer Organization and Design RISC-V Edition: The Hardware Software Interface 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128203315) book.

My questions are:

1. Why are in the sketch, the sign of the numbers ignored, while the final result has a sign bit?
2. In the IEEE 754 standard, there is a hidden '1' bit for normalized numbers. How does this bit take part in addition?

[image]

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have two questions, you can post them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Hidden leading bit: You add a 1 when you extract the mantissa except for denormalised numbers where you add zero.

You use both sign bits to determine whether you add the mantissas (same sign) or subtract (different signs). And the result of the sign comes from the sign of the bigger number.